# Ambiguous Reference to member 'subscript' in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have Search About Ambiguous Reference to member 'subscript' but couldn't find any solution. I am using TableView. this is the Code I am using:-

```
let  people = [
          ["Pankaj Negi" , "Rishikesh"],
          ["Neeraj Amoli" , "Dehradun"],
          ["Ajay" , "Delhi"]
];
// return the number of section
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

// return how many row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count;
}

// what are the content of the cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell();

    var (personName , personLocation) = people[indexPath.row] // Ambiguous Reference to member 'subscript'
    cell.textLabel?.text = personName;

    return cell;

}
```

I am new to IOS Development that why it is difficult for me to understand this. But this code is work in Xcode 6 but not in Xcode 8. why I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think so the same code work for you Xcode 6, what you have done in your Xcode 6 is you have made array of tuple, but currently you are making 2D array means each array element it self having array with two String type element.

So change the declaration of your array to array of tuple will remove that error.

```
let  people = [
      ("Pankaj Negi" , "Rishikesh"),
      ("Neeraj Amoli" , "Dehradun"),
      ("Ajay" , "Delhi")
]
```

Now you will access tuple in your `cellForRowAt``

```
let (personName , personLocation) = people[indexPath.row] 
cell.textLabel?.text = personName
```

**Note:** With Swift no need to add `;` to specify end of statement it is optional unless you want to add Consecutive statement in single line

Comment: Thanks, @Nirav D, I have making 2d array but I need an array of a tuple, in this case, that's why it is showing this error. it is the silly mistake from my side to use '[' in place of '('.